# What is the most efficient way to initialize a Class in Ruby with different parameters and default values?

Tags: ruby, oop, class

I would like to have a class and some attributes which you can either set during initialization or use its default value.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type
  def initialize(color, type)
    @color=color ||= 'green'
    @type=type ||='pear'
  end
end

apple=Fruit.new(red, apple)
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The typical way to solve this problem is with a hash that has a default value. Ruby has a nice syntax for passing hash values, if the hash is the last parameter to a method.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type

  def initialize(params = {})
    @color = params.fetch(:color, 'green')
    @type = params.fetch(:type, 'pear')
  end

  def to_s
    "#{color} #{type}"
  end
end

puts(Fruit.new)                                    # prints: green pear
puts(Fruit.new(:color => 'red', :type => 'grape')) # prints: red grape
puts(Fruit.new(:type => 'pomegranate')) # prints: green pomegranate
```

A good overview is here: http://deepfall.blogspot.com/2008/08/named-parameters-in-ruby.html

Comment: I like this solution the most among the others. The reason is we won't need to create any further significant objects (imagine a big class instance for example) in case the params already has those options. But I also would like to use even cleaner syntax (just my opinion) like this:  @color = params[:color] || 'green'

Comment: I'm going to have an opportunity to do a little ruby/jruby!  After 7 years!

Answer (score 28):

Since Ruby 2.0 there is support of named or keyword parameters.

You may use:

```
class Fruit
  attr_reader      :color, :type

  def initialize(color: 'green', type: 'pear')
    @color = color
    @type = type
  end

  def to_s
    "#{color} #{type}"
  end
end

puts(Fruit.new)                                    # prints: green pear
puts(Fruit.new(:color => 'red', :type => 'grape')) # prints: red grape
puts(Fruit.new(:type => 'pomegranate')) # prints: green pomegranate
```

Some interesting notes on this topic:

- [Keyword arguments in Ruby 2.0](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/)
- [Ruby 2.0.0 by Example](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/)
- [Named parameters in Ruby 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308163/named-parameters-in-ruby-2)

Comment: To be clear, this is by far the best answer here, though as knut said kwargs weren't available until Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 12):

Brian's answer is excellent but I would like to suggest some modifications to make it mostly meta:

```
class Fruit

  # Now this is the only thing you have to touch when adding defaults or properties
  def set_defaults
    @color ||= 'green'
    @type  ||= 'pear'
  end

  def initialize(params = {})
    params.each { |key,value| instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) }
    set_defaults
    instance_variables.each {|var| self.class.send(:attr_accessor, var.to_s.delete('@'))}
  end

  def to_s
    instance_variables.inject("") {|vars, var| vars += "#{var}: #{instance_variable_get(var)}; "}
  end

end

puts Fruit.new
puts Fruit.new :color => 'red', :type => 'grape'  
puts Fruit.new :type => 'pomegranate'
puts Fruit.new :cost => 20.21
puts Fruit.new :foo => "bar"


f = Fruit.new :potato => "salad"
puts "f.cost.nil? #{f.cost.nil?}"
```

Which outputs:

```
@color: green; @type: pear; 
@color: red; @type: grape; 
@color: green; @type: pomegranate; 
@color: green; @type: pear; @cost: 20.21; 
@color: green; @type: pear; @foo: bar; 
f.cost.nil? true
```

Of course this wouldn't be a perfect solution for everything but it gives you some ideas on making your code more dynamic.

Comment: Thank you! I might consider to switch to this later on.

Comment: @l1x Glad I could help. If the info was helpful a vote up would be cool. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it like this:

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type

  def initialize(args={})
    options = {:color => 'green', :type => 'pear'}.merge(args)

    self.color = options[:color]
    self.type  = options[:type]
  end
end

apple = Fruit.new(:color => 'red', :type => 'apple')
```

This way, you never have to worry about missing arguments--or their order--and you'll always have your default values right there. `.merge` will of course overwrite the default values if they're present.

Answer (score 6):

I like vonconrad's answer but would have a separate `defaults` method. Maybe it's not efficient in terms of lines of code, but it's more intention-revealing and involves less cognitive overhead, and less cognitive overhead means more efficient dev onboarding.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type

  def initialize(args={})
    options = defaults.merge(args)

    @color = options.fetch(:color)
    @type  = options.fetch(:type)
  end

  def defaults
    {
      color: 'green',
      type:  'pear'
    }
  end
end

apple = Fruit.new(:color => 'red', :type => 'apple')
```

Answer (score 4):

More simple way:

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type
  def initialize(color = 'green', type = 'pear')
    @color = color
    @type = type
  end
  def to_s
    "#{color} #{type}"
  end
end


puts Fruit.new # prints: green pear
puts Fruit.new('red','apple') # prints: red apple
puts Fruit.new(nil,'pomegranate') # prints: green pomegranate
```

Comment: Yes, except this approach requires that you pass the parameters in order. With the hash approach, you must specify the parameter name (i.e., the hash key), but you can pass those keys in any order.

Answer (score 2):

#### Even more tasty syntactic sugar:

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type
  def initialize *args
    @color, @type = args 
  end
end

pear = Fruit.new 'green', :pear
```

Comment: This doesn’t allow you to set default values.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby version: 3.1

I faced the same issue while trying to initialize my classes with some default values.

The best approach for me was to use "named argument". Check out this [link](https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/learning/methods-arguments-ruby-part2.html) for a better understanding.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :color, :type
  def initialize(color: 'green', type: 'pear')
    @color = color
    @type = type
  end
end

apple=Fruit.new(color: red, type: apple)
```