# CSV code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

What does `header:true do |row|`, `@book<<BookInSTOCK.new`, `row ["ISBN"]` mean in the following code?

```
class CsvReader
  def initialize
    @book_in_stock = []
  end
  def read_in_csv_data(csv_file_name)
    # enter code here
    CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, header: true) do |row|
      @books_in_stock << BoookInStock.new (row["ISBN"], row ["Amount"])
    end
   end
 end
```

Comment: you probably want to learn to format code  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments, I think you should first make yourself familiar with the basic building blocks and the syntax of Ruby.

I know, in the beginning I had tons of similar questions.
I found a very basic and playful approach to learn the basics of the Ruby programming language [in this book](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/).

**To answer your question:**

`CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, header: true)` is a method call to `CSV`. The method `foreach` in this case receives two arguments.

1. `csv_file_name` is a variable that is being defined as the first argument of the outer method `read_in_csv_data`.

   So if you call `CsvReader.new.read_in_csv_data("file.csv")` it will pass the string `"file.csv"` down to `CSV.foreach("file.csv", ...`.
2. `header: true` is basically a Hash, but this style is commonly known as named arguments. Very useful and readable if you want to pass down options to a method that are very specific.

   **How does `CSV.foreach` receive `header: true`?**
   That is easy to find out, open up a `$ irb` session on your local machine, and define the following method:

   ```
   def foo(arg1, arg2)
     p arg1
     p arg2
     nil
   end
   ```

   Now play around by calling `foo` with different arguments.

   ```
   > foo("string", 123)
   "string"
   123
   => nil
   > foo("string", named: "argument")
   "string"
   {:named=>"argument}
   => nil
   > foo("string", { named: "argument" })
   "string"
   {:named=>"argument}
   => nil
   ```

   Doing this you might grasp how Ruby handles named arguments or hash arguments. As you see, the latter examples above show that you can specify a Hash without `{}` as the last argument on any method in Ruby.
   `header: true` represents a Hash, ie `{:header => true}`.

   **What does `header: true` trigger?**
   This has to be read up in the documentation for `CSV::foreach`. You you do a Google search for "ruby csv foreach" you will quickly find a documentation. [Here is a direct link to `CSV::foreach`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/CSV.html#method-c-foreach).
   There you can read *"The options parameter can be anything ::new understands."*. So you gotta look for the [documentation of `CSV::new`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/CSV.html#method-c-new). This leads you to a nice description of each option you can pass to `CSV::new` or `CSV::foreach`.

   **What does the documentation say?**

   > **:headers** If set to **:first_row** or **true**, the initial row of the CSV file
   >   will be treated as a row of headers. If set to an Array, the contents
   >   will be used as the headers. If set to a String, the String is run
   >   through a call of ::parse_line with the same :col_sep, :row_sep, and
   >   :quote_char as this instance to produce an Array of headers. This
   >   setting causes #shift to return rows as CSV::Row objects instead of
   >   Arrays and #read to return CSV::Table objects instead of an Array of
   >   Arrays.

**Your other questions:**

You are welcome to ask questions, but I also think it would be very good for you to get someone to help you directly. Maybe find yourself a [local Ruby user group](http://rubyusergroups.org/). People there are usually very friendly and helpful.

**Having said that, I will now explain what `row["ISBN"]` means:**

`CSV::foreach` is a method that *yields* a block. This block is somewhat similar to a function, and per definition of `CSV::foreach` it lets you do something with *each* row of the csv file.

`row` itself is just a variable name defined in the *block arguments* (ie `|row|`).

Maybe its time for you to open up another `$ irb` and play around with blocks yourself:

```
def foo
  yield 123
end
```

Try calling foo the same way as you do `CSV::foreach`, just that you print the output.

```
> foo do |row| puts row end
123
=> nil
> foo { |arg1| puts arg1 }
123
=> nil
```

As you see `yield 123` is passing `123` as the first argument of the block. You take the first argument in a variable (eg `row` or `arg1`) and you can do something with it in the block. Also note that you can create these blocks with `do |arg1| ... end` but also `{ |arg1| ... }`.

**So what is it with this `["ISBN"]`??**

`row` itself is just a variable, but is also an object so you can call methods on it. In Ruby you might have already encountered a hash.
The contents of a hash in Ruby can be accessed by calling `[]` on the hash.

The same way each row of the CSV is represented. Just that each row (since you told `CSV` to use **:headers**) is being represented as a hash-like object.

If you omit **:headers** each row will be an array of arrays.

Maybe its time for you to open up an `$ irb` and play around with `CSV` directly. For that create yourself a simple csv file like the following, and save it to disk:

```
id,name
1,Overbryd
2,Boniface
3,Poignant
```

Then, open up a `$ irb -r csv`.

```
> CSV.foreach("test.csv") { |r| p r }
["id", "name"]
["1", "Overbryd"]
["2", "Boniface"]
["3", "Poignant"]
=> nil
> CSV.foreach("test.csv", headers: true) { |r| p r }
#<CSV::Row "id":"1" "name":"Overbryd">
#<CSV::Row "id":"2" "name":"Boniface">
#<CSV::Row "id":"3" "name":"Poignant">
=> nil
> CSV.foreach("test.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  puts row["id"]
end
1
2
3
=> nil
```

Also, please accept one of the given answers. People take time to answer your questions, their only reward is if you accept one of their answers.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time to answer my question. I am going to bookmark it till everything becomes a second nature.

Answer (score 1):

> @book << BookInSTOCK.new

Adds a new `BookInSTOCK` object into the `@book` variable [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#3C-3C-method)

> CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, header: true) do |row|

`header:true` is a [named parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308163/named-parameters-in-ruby-2)
In this case it says there is a header in the `csv_file_name`, and here you are looping over each row in the csv file and I'm guessing you will want to get data from each row.

That's where:

> row ["ISBN"]

Is a way to see what the ISBN is in the specific row. Based on the CSV there is most likely other information you can look up in that row.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments below I will add some more context

Let's assume a csv that looks like this

```
ISBN, AMOUNT
1, $30
2, $50
3, $60
```

then let's assume we have this code(It's very close to yours.

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, header: true) do |row|
  puts row["ISBN"]
end
```

Then the output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

As you can see we are [looping](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm) over each row and printing out the information. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can I do header:true do |column|?

row["ISBN"] why I need to use row? cant I use column here too?

Comment: Well you can row is just a variable name, but row is just a representation of each row in the CSV file. If you want to loop over the columns you'll probably have to use a different function.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm. That is just a foreach loop, I'm guessing you're new to programming.

Comment: Updated the answer to hopefully help.

Comment: Here is where I got got confused? isnt all the information are on column? can we use |var| instead of |row|?

Comment: `row` is just a variable name. It could be `mydata` it doesn't really matter, it is just a way to make your code clear as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: You took time to explain. I really appreciate it.

Comment: One last question.

The reason why its saving "ISBN" is because of the header or its saving cause its the key?

Comment: I'm assuming all header information in CSV's are keys for the row object. If you were to have a different CSV with no ISBN in it this code will not work.

Comment: Interesting. Life is easy and you make it easier my friend!

Answer (score 0):

header: true tells the CSV parser that you have a header row in your file.
for example:

```
col1, col2, col3
1, 3, 4
3, 4, 2
```

has a header.

`@books_in_stock <<` adds whatever comes after << to the @books_in_stock array

Comment: Could you elaborate?  what would happen if header:false?

what does row ["ISBN"] means?